# How can I get the posts from a taxonomy in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a custom type called ("knowledge_base") which has a taxonomy called ('section') and one of them is ('dog bite'). Right now I am on example.com/section/dog-bite/ and I am trying to show the posts located here. This is what I have so far so I am not sure what is missing but it just displays ALL the posts from all sections.

```
$current = get_queried_object();

 $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'knowledge_base',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
             'taxonomy'  => 'section',
             'field'    => $current->slug,
             'terms'    => $current->name
             )
         )
       );
 // The Query
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
     echo '<ul>';
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
         $the_query->the_post();
         echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
     }
     echo '</ul>';
 } else {
     // no posts found
 }
```

[There is supposed to be only 2 posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISpkb.png)

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the `field` and `terms`? Also, have you tried ding a var_dump to confirm that `$current->slug` and `$current->name` are the values you expect?

Comment: Yes I just tried that but still shows ALL the posts. I uploaded a screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISpkb.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'knowledge_base',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'section',
            'field'    => 'slug', // ‘term_id’, ‘name’, ‘slug’ or ‘term_taxonomy_id’
            'terms'    => $current->slug, // It's will be $term->slug
        )
    )
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I tried but it still shows ALL the posts. Here is a screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISpkb.png

Comment: @TheAdvocates You need to change your args to use `'field' => 'slug'`, i.e.  the `field` should be the word `'slug'`, not the slug you are looking for. The code in your screenshot shows `'field' => 'dog-bite'`. Show us the outcome when you change it to that, please.